# How to update Symfony routing on an external server with FTP upload only?

Tags: symfony1, routes, upload, ftp

i'm currently adapting an existing Symfony project to my needs and would like to add some static pages. As far as i know, i can add lines to the rounting.yml but after the upload the rountings won't work. Do i have to run any Symfony command and upload other files to update the routings?

Thanks everybody,
Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All yml files are cached in the prod environment for speed. You need to clear your cache - simply delete the contents of the cache directory.